# Creating an Array List from controls after the controls have been dynamcially created

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop

I have a web app that creates new controls, in this case it creates new Rich Textbox controls.

I can’t be sure how many will be created but I need to iterate through each Rich Textbox control and determine what the text string says.

If it says “-“ then I do nothing but if it does not say “-“ then I do something.

I want to use something like this (shown below)

```
Dim labels As New List(Of String) From {...array of Future richtext boxes}
```

and then use something like this to check if an event should be triggered...

```
    Sub NextClicked()
    ' Iterate through the array. 
    For Each item As String In labels
        If item = "-" Then
            'DO NOTHING BECAUSE THERE ARE STILL SOME UNCHECKED BUTTONS
            MsgBox("Do not clear yet")
        Else
            'WRITE ALL DATA TO DB AND CLEAR SCREEN
            MsgBox("clear")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

My Question: How do I build an array from controls once the controls have been dynamically created?

Comment: Why does the array need to be created before the controls are created? Why don't you just create an empty array and then add the controls to the array as they are created? Then you can still iterate through them like in your example. The array simply does not need to be filled before the controls are created.

Comment: How do I add the controls, to the array, as they are created? What I would like to do then is create the controls and add all the controls to an array list, then read the text string of all the controls. If one of them contains "-" then an event will be triggered/ignored.

Comment: One thing you can do is make them all a specific type and then you don't have to worry about the array. Just iterate through all the controls and only check the ones that are of that type. You can create customized types. Unfortunately, its hard to add code to comment boxes, but the other way would be to simply create the empty array as in: Dim whatever as new Array() and then add the controls to the array right after you create them : whatever.add(your_control)

Comment: For more info on using specific types, I explained it in this thread. It is the same concept.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756074/visual-basic-multiple-if-functions-at-once/22762479#22762479